# mysql connectivity issue: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am attemping to establish **Mysql** connectivity to Database using **Java Struts1**. Here the code snippet.Also I added **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** to **web-inf/lib** folder .
Also added the same to classpath variable.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class select {

  public  void connection() {

    System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }.
```

This is Error message. What steps am  I missing. Kindly suggest ASAP.

```
-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Com.Candidjava.select.connection(select.java:14)
    at Com.Candidjava.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:26)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar to your tomcat installation directory as well. And when right click on your project and select build path then libraries. and inside libraries Apache Tomcat you should find your connector jar then only your mysql will work

Comment: You ve to tick the correct answer that gave u the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this is an example of jdbc connection to mysql database:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Connection {

private static java.sql.Connection conex = null;

public static java.sql.Connection getConnectionInstance() {
    if (conex == null) {
        try {
            // connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conex = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName","root",
                    "MySQLPassword");
            return conex;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return conex;
}

}
```

make sure you have opened the port selected during install.

Comment: i make this class as singleton,so I can import conex, which is used to connect to any class that needs to do the query.